# javascript: this keyword

Tags: javascript

I know `this` points to current object on which function operates. So here is the code as per the definition

```
function foo(){
    alert(this); //output==window
}
```

So, now function foo is equal to window.foo()
but now here

```
function foo(){
    function fo(){
        alert(this);
    }
    fo();
}
```

so,now when `foo` gets executed output is again window object why? since the         nested `this` should refer to different object.since fo() is now not operating on window object as foo()==window.foo() .so nested function should now point to different object

see here for detail:

```
 function foo()
{
alert(this);
  function fo(){alert(this);}
as();
}
```

if now,var x=new foo();than "this" within the foo() method points to object object but the nested this points to global object right?now u should be clear what i meant to say

Comment: What do you expect it to equal to? You're still plainly running `fo()` so `this == window`.

Comment: @pimvdb no it is not running plainly.How can it run plainly it is a nested function.

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](http://henrycode.tumblr.com/post/37627169791/javascript-clarifying-the-keyword-this), the keyword `this` is bound dynamically to the object found to the left of the ‘.’ at call time.
There are three exceptions to the above.

1. When there is no `.` the keyword `this` is bound to the global object window.
2. When you use call and apply, you get to decide what `this` is bound to.
3. When you use the keyword new to create a new instance from a constructor, the keyword `this` refers to the newly generated instance.

Since here, you are still calling just `fo()`, `this` is bound to `window`.

Comment: Fast answer :) Regarding the global scope, sometimes it won't be the `window` object due to the execution context having restricted privileges. For instance, if the function is invoked from within a Web Worker.

Answer (score 2):

Two things....

First of all you should look into using the console. (`console.log(this);`).

Second there is a difference between a closure and a scope (`this`).

Closure:

```
function a() {
    function b() {
        // b is only available inside `a`
    } 
}
// so out here b will be undefined
```

Scope:

```
function a() {
    // in here the scope can be multiply things depending on how the function is called. See below
    console.log(this);
}
```

Scope is per default `window`, if the function is a method of an object the scope refers to the object.

```
a(); // logs: window

var o = { 
    a: a
};
o.a(); // logs: { a: a }
```

You can overwrite this defalt behaviors by using ether call or apply

```
var s = [1, 2, 3]
a.call(s); // logs: [1, 2, 3]
// or using apply
a.apply(s) // logs: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The first snippet is usually referred to as "scope". The `this` value is more often called "context".

Answer (score 1):

The `this` value depends on how the function is *called*, not how it is *defined*. If you have the following function:

```
var test = function() {
  console.log(this);
};
```

Then there are numerous ways to call it:

- `test()` - it will be `window`
- `new test()` - it will be the instance
- `({ foo: test }).foo()` - it will be the object
- `test.call(bar)` - it will be `bar`

Whether a function is nested or not doesn't matter.

Comment: it's more detailed here http://doctrina.org/Javascript-Function-Invocation-Patterns.html#ci

Answer (score 0):

Programming, you're doing it wrong.

To make fo an function of the object you should do this:

```
function foo(){
    this.fo = function(){
       alert(this);
    }
}
f = new foo();
f.fo();
```

see how the fo function is initiated in the object declaration?

Now when you do `f.fo()` you get `[object Object]`

Comment: oo now i have to explain u in detail watch this code carefully.function foo(){function(){alert(this);}}  now, when x=new foo() ,the "this" within the method points to global object right since it is nested one right?

Comment: @MaizerePathak I know, but it's basically the same. Just trying to explain to you how things works.

Comment: @NULL anyhow thanks for your post.But was not to the point i wanted